# Facebook Audience Network not show real ads in device

Tags: ios, facebook-audience-network

1 month ago I have Integrated Facebook Audience Network (FAN) successfully in my iOS app. But today I am trying to see real ads in real device but I never see real ads,always shows 'Server Error'. But I can see test ads only. Hence I am unable to enter review process.

Likewise before, I follow these 4 steps to see real ads

1. I am testing on physical device not in simulator
2. I have installed Facebook app on my device/iPhone
3. I am logged into Facebook on my test device with my admin id of the app.
4. I did not use any mediation

Note: FAN has added a new option **Ad Space**. So, I have created an **Ad Space** and then create **Placement ID**.

Comment: I am also getting this same problem, after i tried with real ads instead of test ads. How did you solved it?